# Storing ID, not Name on DB when using Dependent Dropdown - Laravel/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-6

I'm working with dependent dropdown select. I'm trying to get the value name from a list to store in my DB, but I getting only the index (number). How to solve this? Can you help me?

I have these codes:

HTML

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
 <label for="state">State:</label>
  <select name="state"class="form-control state" id="state" onchange="ChangecatList()" required >
   <option selected>Select State...</option>
    @foreach($state as $k => $v)
   <option value="{{$k}}" name="$key">{{ $k }}</option>
    @endforeach
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
 <label for="city">City/ City:</label>
  <select class="form-control city" id="city" placeholder="City"  name="city"></select>
</div>
```

JS

```
var catAndActs = {};

catAndActs['AC'] = ['City1','City2'];

function ChangecatList() {
    var catList = document.getElementById("state");
    var actList = document.getElementById("city");
    var selCat = catList.options[catList.selectedIndex].value;
    while (actList.options.length) {
        actList.remove(0);
    }
    var cats = catAndActs[selCat];
    if (cats) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < cats.length; i++) {
            var cat = new Option(cats[i], i);
            actList.options.add(cat);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Laravel 6 - When I debug -> dd($request), it show me that I'm getting the index.

LARAVEL

```
+request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#52 ▼
    #parameters: array:14 [▼
      "_token" => "kYkq2DhQ7v5XPjY8Aql7gPu5uWnoDYIxRDQXGza2"
      "state" => "AC"
      "city" => "7" // <- here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply place the value as the second parameter to get the city as the value as shown below

```
var cat = new Option(cats[i], cats[i]);
```

You may find the constructor documented here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option